# Support meaning for R arules

Tags: r, associations

I have been struggling with the meaning of support in the `arules` package in R.

I have limited the `lhs` to 1 by passing it a `maxlen=2` and `minlen=2`. For some reason if I pass `maxlen=1` and `minlen=1`, I get an empty `lhs`.

Assuming that I have :

```
Product A => product B  support 4%

Product A => product C  support 2%
```

What is the meaning of support? I thought that support is the proportion that the amount of product `A` appears in the transactions. If this is the case though, support for the previous example should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the combination of lhs and rhs.

A,B appears 4% of the transactions.

A,C appears in 2% of the transactions.

Comment: You are right! Just checked it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: could you also provide me a detailed formula for the confidence? for example for the A,B?

Comment: Conf (a,b) = support (a+b) / support (a)